# error when executing query using sqlcommand in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, web-applications, sql-server-2012

Here's my code:

```
string createString = "CREATE TABLE user (uid INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), uname NVARCHAR(30), uemail NVARCHAR(30), upass NVARCHAR(20), ucontact INT(10))"; //YOUR SQL COMMAND TO CREATE A TABLE

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DELL\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=1000000;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False");

SqlCommand create = new SqlCommand(createString, connection);

connection.Open();
create.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

I get the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and
>   where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect
>   syntax near the keyword 'user'.

Answer (score 5):

`user` is a [reserved keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) in T-SQL. You need to use it with square brackets like `[user]`

As best practice, change it to *non*-reserved word.

Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection and commands automatically instead of calling `Close` method manually.

```
using(var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using(var create = connection.CreateCommand())
{
     create.CommandText = "...";
     connection.Open();
     create.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Table name `user` is predefined word, change table name
or use [user] and also column `ucontact` has datatype int with size, `int` will not accept size. That should be `ucontact INT`
Finaly your query will look like this

```
CREATE TABLE [user] (uid INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), uname NVARCHAR(30), uemail NVARCHAR(30), upass NVARCHAR(20), ucontact INT)
```